Excel conditional formatting based on a cell from every sheet excluding the current sheet
I currently am making a spreadsheet and am doing some data validation, making sure there are no duplicates. I want to check that the cell M3 doesn't match the cell M3 in another sheet. However, I am having some trouble finding a way to make it check against M3 in every sheet rather than just one. I know I could make 15+ conditional formatting rules per sheet, but I was hoping there was some way to automate this.
Right now I have this as a conditional formatting rule: =AND(M3<>"", M3<>0, M3<>"DNF", M3<>"DNS", M3<>"DSQ", Luka!M3<>"", M3=Luka!M3) which checks M3 in the current sheet against M3 in the sheet I named Luka and will flag it if it's the same (unless it's DNF, DNS, DSQ, blank, or 0). However, I also want it to check, if possible, against the sheets Eyk, Finn, Clemens, and so on. I've tried some ways, but there is also the character limit with excel conditional formatting of 255 characters which has made this difficult.

You can do it with an Excel Function, which will be the conditional formatting rule.
This example checks activesheet's cell A1 against all the other sheets' cells A1 and does a conditional formatting with these settings.

Function CondFormat(rng As Range) As Boolean
Application.Volatile

BaseValue = rng

CondFormat = False
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

If ws.Range(rng.Address) = BaseValue And ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
    CondFormat = True
    Exit Function
End If

Next ws

End Function


In Conditional formatting -> New Rule -> Use a formula to determine which cells to format in the Format values where this condition is True box type
=CondFormat(A1)  use cell address to compare to for the argument
Set the format of the cell as needed, or use the True/False result for further processes.


Do you happen to know of any way to do this in the online version? It works on the desktop version, but this is for a project in collaboration with several other people and live editing is invaluable.
